# Ball in a $k$-regular tree

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $X$ be a finite k-regular graph. Fix a vertex $x_0$ and, for $r <\frac{g(X)}{2}$, consider the ball centered at $x_0$ and of radius r in X. Show that it is isometric to any ball with the same radius in the $k$-regular tree $T_k$. Compute the cardinality of such a ball.

I have no clue.

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the ball centered at $x_0$ with radius $r < \frac{g(X)}{2}$. Show that the graph induced by the vertices of this ball cannot contain any cycle.

Comment: @DavidHackenger I argue by contradiction. If $x_0$ doesn't belong to the cycle, then it is linked to $i$ vertices of the cycle and to other $k-i$ vertices. If $x_0$ is linked to two consecutive vertices, we have $g(X)=3$ (since there is a cycle containing $x_0$ of length 3), so there exists surely a vertex $v_j$ whose distance from $x_0$ is strictly greater than $r$. What about the case in which $x_0$ is contained in the cycle or if it is linked to two non-consecutive vertices of the cycle? I have a counterexample when $k=2$, $r=1$ and $g(X)=3$, namely when the induced subgraph is $C_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in question $r<\frac{g(X)}{2}$ should be $r<[\frac{g(X)-1}{2}]$ where $[x]$ is the greatest integer number below $z$. As for enough big $k$, we can have a path in $B(x_0,r)$ with length $1+r+r$ and if $g(X)$ be an odd number then with ex-bound of $r$ in question, the length of this path will be $1+[\frac{g(X)}{2}]+[\frac{g(X)}{2}]=g(X)$ and we may fail. But with the new bound this case never happens. Also your example in comments shows that without putting any condition on $k$, this new bound on $r$ is sharp for your isomorphism.

Comment: And which is, in general, the cardinality of this ball?